# Pytest strange ImportError

Tags: python, virtualenv, pytest

I am running into a strange issue when running PyTest on my project. The project structure looks something like this.

```
myproject
├── env
│   └── stuff
├── __init__.py
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── myfile.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── framework
        └── unit
            └── test_myfile.py
```

The code in myproject/myproject runs fine.Additionally there are folders with code in myproject root that reference code in myproject/myproject as a module.

But when I run pytest using the following syntax (inside the virutalenv)

```
(env) myproject $ python3.6 -m pytest tests/framework
```

All of tests fail with the following error messages:

```
E           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.tests'


E               _pytest.nodes.Collector.CollectError: ImportError while importing test module '/home/myuser/projects/myproject/tests/__init__.py'.
E               Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
E               Traceback:
E               ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.tests'
```

The output of

```
(env) myproject $ python3.6 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
```

is

```
/home/myuser/projects/myproject/env/lib/python36.zip
/home/myuser/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6
/home/myuser/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3.6
/home/myuser/projects/myproject/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

And going by answers in other posts, even if I manually add myproject, myproject/myproject and myproject/tests to the path through a .pth file, I get the same error messages.

What DOES fix the error messages is to add an empty folder in myproject/myproject called tests. After that is done, the error messages go away and the tests run fine. Can anyone explain what is causing this strange behavior?

Comment: Your setup is extremely weird. Why do you have a "top-level" `__init__.py`?  I believe you are confusing pytest by having that `__init__` so it is trying to look for `tests` inside that directory.

Comment: What line is triggering the error?  Is your code trying to import `myproject.tests` despite, apparently, being fine with not doing anything with it?

Comment: @jwodder The error messages all come from files in env/. It's not being referenced anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Bakuriu The project was inherited and structured as such when I got it. Deleting the top level __init__ solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Issue with some dynamical imports, and I saw that this could solve my Issue

If you check the class `ContextImport`, at line 46, on this file [ekiim/panflute/utils.py](https://github.com/ekiim/panflute/blob/master/panflute/utils.py) (Github Code)

What that class does, is It works as a context manager, so you can give, it a file (with its absolute path), and it will import the file into that context.

So maybe by modifying this context manager, you could, your project directory into the path, and then revert the change (when exiting the context).

That class works by putting the path in the first entry of the `sys.path` list, maybe that was your problem and you were just appending to the path list.

Still, I'm not sure if this could be considered correct or pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a top level `__init__.py` that should not have been there.

As suggested by [bakuriu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615119/pytest-strange-importerror#comment92164872_52615119):

> Your setup is extremely weird. Why do you have a "top-level"
> `__init__.py`? I believe you are confusing `pytest` by having that `__init__.py` so it is trying to look for tests inside that directory.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52615119/3) to the question [Pytest strange ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615119/pytest-strange-importerror) by the OP [Manderton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3745521/manderton) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Answer (score -4):

You have to be inside your test directory when running commands for Pytest to locate your test_*.py files.

Try researching `if __name__ == "__main__":` but check the Pytest documentation for anti-patterns and abstractions first. You may not need this step if your architecture follows Pytest standards.

Comment: The first paragraph is absolutely not true.  The second paragraph says almost nothing.